# foreach inside foreach issue

Tags: php, foreach, scandir

I have two directories : one has images and the other has ZIP files.
The files in both directories have the same names e.g : 1.zip , 1.png

I scanned each folder like this :

```
$images    = 'screenshots/';
$scanned_images = array_diff(scandir($images), array('..', '.'));
$zips = 'download/';
$scanned_zips = array_diff(scandir($zips), array('..', '.'));
```

then :

```
foreach ($scanned_images as $value)
{
echo '<div class="portfolioItem">';
echo '<a href="screenshots/'.$value.'" class="zoom img" title="'.$value.'"      rel="portfolio">';
echo '<img src="screenshots/'.$value.'" class="portfolio-image" alt="'.$value.'" /> </a>';
foreach ($scanned_zips as $val)
{
echo '<div class="portfolioDescription">';
echo'<h4>Download:'.$val.'</h4>';
echo'<p><a href="download/'.$val.'">Click here to download</a></p>';
echo'</div></div>';
}
}
```

This does not work. Each image in first directory will have the whole zip files of second directory in its description!

I have also tried to combine the two arrays into one array and use `foreach ($result as list ($a, $b))` but `as list` always gives an error.

How to overcome this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need to have nested foreach.

use this:

```
<?php

$images    = 'screenshots/';
$scanned_images = array_diff(scandir($images), array('..', '.'));
$zips = 'download/';
$scanned_zips = array_diff(scandir($zips), array('..', '.'));

foreach ($scanned_images as $value)
{
    $name = substr($value, 0, strrpos($value, '.'));
    $pos = array_search($name.'.zip', $scanned_zips);
    if($pos != null){
        echo '<div class="portfolioItem">';
        echo    '<a href="'.$images.$value.'" class="zoom img" title="'.$value.'" rel="portfolio">';
        echo        '<img src="'.$images.$value.'" class="portfolio-image" alt="'.$value.'" />';
        echo    '</a>';
        echo    '<div class="portfolioDescription">';
        echo        '<h4>Download:'.$scanned_zips[$pos].'</h4>';
        echo        '<p><a href="'.$zips.$scanned_zips[$pos].'">Click here to download</a></p>';
        echo    '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! This works except for one problem. it is not listing all of the array. Only 5 out of 31 images and zip files. I can't figure out what cause this.

Comment: I found that the missing files have not exactly the same name. Uppercase and lowercase. Now it works. THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

One way is to hash your files by name without extension. Then use same key to retrieve image data and zip data. Example:

```
$scanned_images = array('1.png', '2.png');
$scanned_zips = array('1.zip', '2.zip');

//Should be like that after hashing
$scanned_images = array('1' => '1.png', '2' => '2.png');
$scanned_zips = array('1' => '1.zip', '2' => '2.zip');
```

So the code could be:

```
function get_file_name($path) {
    $name = basename($path);
    $name = substr($name, 0, strrpos($name, '.'));
    return $name;
}

function hash_files_by_name($items) {
    $hashed = array();
    foreach($items as $item) {
        $name = get_file_name($item);
        $hashed[$name] = $item;
    }

    return $hashed;
}


$scanned_images = array('1.png', '2.png'); // get images directory filesnames
$scanned_zips = array('1.zip', '2.zip'); // get zips directory filenames.

$imgs = hash_files_by_name($scanned_images);
$zips = hash_files_by_name($scanned_zips);

foreach ($imgs as $key=>$value)
{
    echo '<div class="portfolioItem">';
    echo '<a href="screenshots/'.$value.'" class="zoom img" title="'.$value.'"      rel="portfolio">';
    echo '<img src="screenshots/'.$value.'" class="portfolio-image" alt="'.$value.'" /> </a>';
    if(isset($zips[$key])) {
        echo '<div class="portfolioDescription">';
        echo'<h4>Download:'.$zips[$key].'</h4>';
        echo'<p><a href="download/'.$zips[$key].'">Click here to download</a></p>';
        echo'</div></div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: any ideas why I got minus?

Answer (score 0):

Add a [`break;`](http://php.net/break) statement at the end of your inner `foreach` loop and that should fix it. You have two `foreach` loops and hence the downloads are listed multiple times. To fix this issue,

Change your code to:

```
<?php
foreach ($scanned_images as $value)
{
echo '<div class="portfolioItem">';
echo '<a href="screenshots/'.$value.'" class="zoom img" title="'.$value.'"      rel="portfolio">';
echo '<img src="screenshots/'.$value.'" class="portfolio-image" alt="'.$value.'" /> </a>';
    foreach ($scanned_zips as $val)
    {
    echo '<div class="portfolioDescription">';
    echo'<h4>Download:'.$val.'</h4>';
    echo'<p><a href="download/'.$val.'">Click here to download</a></p>';
    echo'</div></div>';
    break; //exiting
    }
}

?>
```